# Assets plugin has no files in Multiple Site Manager 2nd site

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager

When I choose to copy everything with MSM in order to create a new site, the Assets plugin file meta-data is not copied over. I was hoping that the images in the Assets plugin would be available for all sites, or at a bare minimum, when copying a site, the ones from the original site would be copied in the DB so that the new site would not have all images broken.

Has anyone done anything more elegant than fixing them one by one?
I figured someone has run into this and has an update statement that could get me started to duplicate all the meta data associated with each file in the DB.

Oddities of note:  I am setting the $config['upload_preferences'] array in my config file and have not followed the MSM documentation on creating separate vhosts and folder trees for additional sites, choosing instead to set the specific values MSM requires in index.php and admin.php conditionally on $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].  I also have all of my assets in a symlink folder so all the sites can use the same path.  Hopefully none of those implementation details are a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Jared,

The data for those add-ons will not be copied; only the structure. We'd need a well placed hook in the MSM to be able to copy the data over as well.  So definitely some database finagling if you want to copy that data over.

Comment: Can you give me a general idea what I would need to do to manually copy the data over?

Comment: You'd need to look at the Assets tables, copy that, update site_ids; depending on custom fields and channels, you'll need to build those associations with updated site_ids as well.  I'd definitely recommend doing this in development first.